# z-index with two relative positioned elements IE7

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7, css, z-index

I have two elements. One is a searchbox that has to be positioned relatively.  The other is an image I would like to overlap part of the search box and it has to be positioned relatively as well. No matter what I set the z-index to, IE7 won't overlap the image.  It goes underneath the searchbox.  It overlaps and works in Firefox though.  Help? Thanks

Comment: Anywhere hosted? or Jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

z-index will only come into play when the element is positioned absolutely. Something you could try would be to have the image positioned absolutely and wrapped in a relative-ly positioned div, since the position is taken from the parent element.

Hope that's clear, let me know if you need more detail

Comment: Actually, z-index should work for position: relative, absolute, or fixed

Answer (score 0):

There is a z-index bug in IE7.

This may help: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/64774ff1-1cce-4666-a2c7-9a899994aaef

Answer (score 0):

We need some code to look at. If your structure is something similar to this:

```
<div style="z-index: 1">
  <input style="z-index: 1; position: relative;" type="text" name="search" /> 
  <img style="z-index: 2; position: relative;" > 
</div>
```

It should work.